# OpenOCD - Can't find target/swj-dp.tcl

Tags: debugging, stm32, openocd

I have troubles to use OpenOCD. For some reasons OpenOCD **can't find swj-dp.tcl** but the file is existing in C:\OpenOCD\share\openocd\scripts\target.

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.9.0 (2015-08-15-12:41)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
C:\OpenOCD\share\openocd\scripts\target\stm32f1x.cfg:6: Error: Can't find target/swj-dp.tcl
in procedure 'script' 
at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 60
at file "C:\OpenOCD\share\openocd\scripts\target\stm32f1x.cfg", line 6
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSc7p.png)

Do you have any idea or advice for me? Thank you

Comment: include error message in text :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that `openocd` configuration files are TCL scripts which include other scripts. And those included scripts are searched for only in provided search directories (IIRC, by default only current directory). So you need to provide additional search directories:

```
openocd -s C:\OpenOCD\share\openocd\scripts -f ...
```

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP and it persists even when using the -s flag and the correct path to the scripts folder. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: @SimonCarlson Can you port your error message somewhere?

Comment: I posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673651/cannot-find-script-files-with-openocd